# Japaneses Charset not supporting in email

Tags: php, email

HI i am using php `charset=utf-8` for sending email.

Please check my code:

```
<?php
function sendEmail($to,$from,$subject,$message){

$message = "<table><tr><td>".$message."</td></tr></table>";
$bcc1 = "c*******@gmail.com";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'From:' .$from."\r\n";
$headers.= 'BCC:' .$bcc1."\r\n";

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){

    echo "Email sent";
}
else{
    echo "Email failed";
}
}


$getSettings = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name='WELCOME_EMAIL'"));
$msg = $getSettings['body'];
$subject = $getSettings['display'];
$from = "l********@gmail.com"           
$message = mb_convert_encoding($msg, "ISO-2022-JP","UTF-8");
sendEmail($to,$from,$subject,$message);

?>
```

I have sending email using above code but i am not getting the proper Japanese format text.

Please see the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the mail problem but the `charset` could be `ISO-2022-JP` not `utf-8`.

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-2022-JP \n";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Naota you are right.

But when you fetch content from data base before fetching you have to use the below php code

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci');
```

so that japan character are fetch from database